# Ubuntu 19.10 not booting on Threadripper but 18.04 will

Tags: boot, usb

So my new system (Threadripper 3970x on Gigabyte TRX40 AORUS MASTER) doesn't boot on Ubuntu 19.10 - it gets stuck at recognizing USB devices:

```
7-6 New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608
7-6 New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, Serialnumber.....
7-6 Product: USB2.0 Hub
7-6:1.0: USB hub found
7-6:1.0: 4 ports detected
```

..then nothing happens. This is the same on booting from USB stick, normal boot and recovery mode.

I tried removing USB devices, but this hub seems to be on the motherboard. What can I do? Since I can't even enter recovery mode it seems a bit tricky to troubleshoot. Can I disable specific USB ports through GRUB maybe? Or is the listed USB entry not even the problem?

Comment: Now I tried Ubuntu 18.04 (already had it on a stick). Indeed, this one boots successfully - it just reports some UEFI issues. So, any ideas on how to fix the 19.10 installation? Or do I need to make a full reinstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an `mce=off` line to your kernel parameters if you wish you use kernel version 5.39 - the default kernel for Ubuntu 19.10.

See:  https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Boot-Threadripper-Zen2MCE

I edited my grub config by booting into Ubuntu with the 4.15 Kernel as found in my grub menu and then using `grub-customizer` to add the parameter.

Comment: Yes! Simply adding mce=off as a parameter in GRUB solved the problem. Thanks so much for your help!